# Convert json data to csv with python3 but it doesn't work

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a large data set contain a set of numbers

The data is fetched from server

Each row of data is like this:

```
{"body_data":[
{'height': 170.00, 'weight': 165.00, 'blood': 3.00, 'sugar': 100.02, 'fat': 36.02, 'time_object': 1544443260000},
{'height': 170.00, 'weight': 165.00, 'blood': 3.00, 'sugar': 100.02, 'fat': 36.02, 'time_object': 1544443260000},
],"symbol":"DATA_FAT","empty":false}
```

I tried to save the data into *.json format the import it as new file and rewrite it with csv yet I got error.

I tried with pandas the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index',columns=['open', 'height', 'weight', 'blood', 'sugar', 'fat', 'time_object'])
```

it gave me the following error:

```
 File "pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx", line 1517, in pandas._libs.lib.to_object_array
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Please paste the full error message, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need select nested key `body_data`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['body_data'])
print (df)
   blood    fat  height   sugar    time_object  weight
0    3.0  36.02   170.0  100.02  1544443260000   165.0
1    3.0  36.02   170.0  100.02  1544443260000   165.0
```

If want change ordering of columns (`open` key is not in sample data, so `NaN`s in output):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['body_data'],
                  columns=['open', 'height', 'weight', 'blood', 'sugar', 'fat', 'time_object'])
print (df)
   open  height  weight  blood   sugar    fat    time_object
0   NaN   170.0   165.0    3.0  100.02  36.02  1544443260000
1   NaN   170.0   165.0    3.0  100.02  36.02  1544443260000
```

Comment: Thank you very much problem solved, yes you are right i selected the body_data and now it works well.